# how to simulated multiple inheritance pattern in F#?

Tags: inheritance, f#

I have one class **Service** and One interface **IService**. I want to implement this two to **ExampleService** class.

I know C# and in C# we can do this using below code

```
class ExampleService : Service, IService
{
}
```

How can i do in F#.Thanks.

Comment: Inheriting from a class and also implementing an interface is still single-inheritance. Neither C# nor F# supports multiple inheritance (inheriting from two or more classes).

Comment: @JoelMueller- I means that how to simulated multiple inheritance pattern in F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type ExampleService() =
    inherit Service()

    interface IService with
    // Below is interface implementation
        member x.ImplementedInterfaceMember() = 
            ...
```

Comment: How does your answer add anything, at all, to mine? The only thing you've changed from the final paragraph is the member inside the interface.

Comment: It doesn't. I think it just have less noise. And interfaces are not always  generic.

Answer (score 4):

First, lets take a look in the interface syntax in the F# wiki page [here:](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Interfaces)

```
open System

type Person(name : string, age : int) = 
 member this.Name = name
 member this.Age = age

(* IComparable is used for ordering instances *)
 interface IComparable<Person> with
    member this.CompareTo(other) =
        (* sorts by name, then age *)
        match this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name) with
        | 0 -> this.Age.CompareTo(other.Age)
        | n -> n

(* Used for comparing this type against other types *)
 interface IEquatable<string> with
    member this.Equals(othername) = this.Name.Equals(othername)
```

As you can see, interfaces are included inside classes, and their functionality is described via the keyword `with`.

Now let's see the inheritence module as it's described in the official [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233225.aspx) site:

```
type MyClassBase1() =
  let mutable z = 0
  abstract member function1 : int -> int
  default u.function1(a : int) = z <- z + a; z

type MyClassDerived1() =
  inherit MyClassBase1()
  override u.function1(a: int) = a + 1
```

Here, the other class is written outside, and the implementation/overrides come after the keyword `inherits`.

So, in your case:

```
type Service()=
 (* Service parent class details here *)

type ExampleService() = 
 inherit Service()
 (* More stuff about the parent class here, i.e overrides *)
 interface IService<ExampleClass> with
 (* Add here the interface details. *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit tangential to the *content* of the original question, but the answers here don't address the more general *title* of the question which is currently pushing this to the top search result for "F# multiple inheritance".

It is possible to simulate multiple inheritance through serial inheritance:

```ml
type A() =
    member z.hello a = $"Hello %s{a}"

type B() =
    inherit A()
    member z.goodbye a = $"Goodbye %s{a}"

type C() =
    inherit B()
    member z.howAreYou n = $"%s{z.hello n}, how are you?"

let c = C()
c.howAreYou "world"
```

Every instance of `C` will have the members of `A` and `B` here.

Another alternative is composition instead of inheritance where the classes which implement the desired functionality are properties of the composing class:

```ml
type A() =
    member z.hello a = $"Hello %s{a}"

type B() =
    member z.goodbye a = $"Goodbye %s{a}"

type C(a: A, b: B) =
    member z.A = a
    member z.B = b
    member z.howAreYou n = $"%s{z.A.hello n}, how are you?"


let c = C(A(), B())
c.howAreYou "world"
```

As noted by Joel in the comments, the original post isn't actually describing multiple inheritance. But, in good faith, OP's query could be answered by inheriting from `Service` and implementing `IService` in `ExampleService` as A. Abramov explained. (Though, from a design perspective, I would expect `Service` to be implementing `IService`, but that wasn't the question.)

```ml
type IService =
    abstract member greet: string -> string

type Service() =
    member z.serve n = $"%s{n}, your dinner is served"

type ExampleService() =
    inherit Service()

    interface IService with
        member z.greet n = "Welcome to chez sharp, %s{n}"

let e = ExampleService()
(e :> IService).greet "world"
```

However, as noted in the [MSDN docs on interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/interfaces), one must call interface members explicitly through the use of the upcast operator. Depending on your use case, this extra step may make serial inheritance or composition a better solution with serial inheritance being the closest to multiple inheritance.